# c/c++ syslog to custom file (not /var/log/syslog but /var/log/mylog) - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, syslog

I successfully tested the following syslog "hello world" example on ubuntu 12.04:

```
// gcc giuspexample.c -o giuspexample

#include <syslog.h>

int  main()
{
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));

    openlog("atm", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);

    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Program started by User %d", getuid ());
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "A tree falls in a forest");

    closelog();
    return 0;
}
```

and I can read the entry in /var/log/syslog.
I followed the instructions on http://www.codealias.info/technotes/syslog_simple_example on how to change the destination filepath

```
echo "local0.*  /var/log/mylog" >> /etc/syslog.conf
```

but trying to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/syslog restart
```

doesn't work (command not found) and rebooting the pc anyway doesn't start to write on /var/log/mylog but still on /var/log/syslog.
Does anybody know what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `/etc/rsyslog.d` directory, there are two files:

1. `20-ufw.conf`
2. `50-default.conf`

I added the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/30-mycustomname.conf` with `sudo nano`, with the following content:

```
# Log QSD Centro generated log messages to file
if $programname == 'centro' then /var/log/centro.log
# Uncomment the following to stop logging anything that matches the last rule.
& ~
```

Then I check that the file `/var/log/centro.log` does not exist

```
sudo rm -f /var/log/centro.log
```

Then I restart the service

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Finally The following code works:

```
// gcc centro.c -o centro

#include <stdio.h>
#include <syslog.h>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    openlog(NULL, 0, LOG_USER);

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "MORTACCI TUA!!!");

    closelog();
    return 0;
}
```